# How to render seperated JSONs in react that are correlated

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, odata

I am reading two JSON files, and only once I read one I will know the child of the other.

Example:

File: "/user.js"

```
{Users:[name: "John", profession: "writer"],[name: "May", profession: "none"]}
```

File: "/ages.js"

```
{ages:{Jack:{age:66}},{John:{age:45}}}
```

```js
render(){    
    <div>
    First Worker {Users[0].name} <!-- Only now I will know his name-->

    Is {ages.X.age} years old <!-- X should be John, I wanted to do something like {ages.Users[0].name.age} -->
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you use `ages[Users[0].name].age`?

Comment: That was a good idea but it doesn't work...

Comment: JSON is a **string** format that contains encoded data. If you want to work with the data you have to parse the JSON **string** to get the encoded actual data.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? what is the problem with it?

Comment: it says error undefined, may have to do with react and lifcycles

Answer (score 1):

File: "/user.js" and "/ages.js" are not a valid JSON files, let's check it at https://jsonlint.com.

A valid JSON file could be:

**File: "/user.js"**

```
{"Users": [{"name": "John","profession": "writer"},{"name": "May","profession": "none"}]}
```

**File: "/ages.js"**

```
{"ages": [{"Jack": {"age": 66}},{"John": {"age": 45}}]}
```

After you change that that the solution of **cowCrazy** should work.

In javascript you can access the key-value of an object as an associative array, let's look that example:

```
var users = {"name":"cowCrazy"};
var tmp = "name";

console.log(users.name);
console.log(users["name"]);
console.log(users[tmp]);
```

The three console.log will show the same result: "cowCrazy".

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the cheap example, that was not the problem, the problem is with react.js and life cycles, I solved this by working before the render. I think while rendering this was not possible